# Sarpa Raksha mantra and sandhya vandanam

Tags: mantras, naga, story

> नर्मदायै नमः प्रातः नर्मदायै नमो निशि
> नमोऽस्तु नर्मदे तुभ्यं त्राहि मां विषसर्पदः
> सर्पापसर्प भद्रं त गच्छ सर्प महाविष।
> जनमेजयस्य यज्ञान्ते आस्तीकवचं स्मर।।
> जरत्कार्वोर्जरत्कर्वां समुत्पन्न महायशाः
> अस्तीक सत्यसन्धो मां पन्नगेभ्यो अभिरक्षतु

Meaning -

> O Narmada, I offer you salutations in the morning & night (during sandhya vandana); Protect me O virulent snake, recollecting the words of Astika at the end of King Janamejaya’s sacrifice, may you go away.
> from poisonous snakes
> Astika, born of muni Jaratkaru and his wife of the same name, was a great soul. He, the protector of the truth, will protect me from the serpents.

1. I want to know the story of Astika and why did Astika want to save the snakes? I have known that the snake sacrifice was done in order to revenge Parikshit's death, but isn't that wrong since Parikshit was cursed? Did Janamejaya incur sin for performing such a snake sacrifice?
2. What was the benefits of this mantra, does it annihilate Sarpa dosha?

Comment: See Astika parva of Adi Parva of Mahabharata.

Comment: It would be helpful if it was narrated as an answer :-)

Comment: There are more than dozen chapters on this. Please read there.

Comment: I just wanted to know why Astika helped the snakes? what relation he had with the snakes, Also did Janamejaya incur sin for snake sacrifice?

Comment: Astika's mother is the daughter of Vasuki, King of Snakes. i.e. Astika is half-snake & half-human. Hence, when he heard of what Janamejeya was doing, he simply ventured out there and we know the rest. Vasuki planned the entire thing actually. 
Read Asktika Parva in Adi Parva of Mahabharata for full story. He promises to Janamejeya that whosoever remembers him (Astika i.e.) will never be bitten by a snake.

Comment: Oh, Why didn't Astika fall into the snake sacrifice?